# MS Office Firefox Plugin (NPAPI)

Tags: javascript, firefox, ms-office

I am having trouble getting a Microsoft Office document to open in FireFox - using Microsoft's Office 2010 plugin.

Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407576.aspx

I am trying it with the following html document in firefox.  I have confirmed that the MS Office 2010 plugin is installed.

```
    <doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function OpenWebDavDocument(url, extension) {
        debugger;
        var hownowPlugin = document.getElementById("winFirefoxPlugin");
        hownowPlugin.EditDocument2(url, null)
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object id="winFirefoxPlugin" type=”application/x-sharepoint">
        <a href="#" onclick="OpenWebDavDocument('bfd42001/hownow/files/Records/12182', 'xlsx')" style="">Excel Doc</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="OpenWebDavDocument('hbfd42001/hownow/files/Records/8924', 'docx')" style="">Word Doc</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am getting the following error when inspecting in FireBug:

hownowPlugin.EditDocument2 is not a function

Can anyone please point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't see a question being asked here, and saying "I am having trouble" with no description of what that "trouble" might be or any error messages you're receiving isn't useful. Please edit your text to ask an actual question and clarify what problem you're experiencing, so that we have information with which to try and help you. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

There was one additional change I made to get the link to work.

Currently, you have:

```
hownowPlugin.EditDocument2(url, null);
```

I removed the 2:

```
hownowPlugin.EditDocument(url, null);
```

Documentation for the FFWinPlugin can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407576.aspx .

I'm doing a similar project where I need to support multiple browsers.  My original edit code was from Milton ( http://milton.io/index.html ).  It only worked in IE.  Pooling together the IE code and the Firefox code, I was able to come up with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fNewDoc = false;
    var EditDocumentButton = null;
    try {
        EditDocumentButton = new ActiveXObject('SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3');
        if (EditDocumentButton != null) { fNewDoc = true; }
    } catch(e) {}

    var L_EditDocumentError_Text = "Editing not supported.";
    var L_EditDocumentRuntimeError_Text = "Sorry, couldn't open the document.";

    function editDocument(strDocument) {
        if (fNewDoc) {
            if (!EditDocumentButton.EditDocument(strDocument)) {
                alert(L_EditDocumentRuntimeError_Text);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                var hownowPlugin = document.getElementById("winFirefoxPlugin");
                hownowPlugin.EditDocument(strDocument, null);
            } catch (e) { alert(L_EditDocumentError_Text); }
        }
    }
</script>
<object id="winFirefoxPlugin" type="application/x-sharepoint" width="0" height="0" style="visibility: hidden;"></object>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have that plugin, but maybe it doesn't work because of a typo (error on the Microsoft page). You have

```
type=”application/x-sharepoint"
```

instead of

```
type="application/x-sharepoint"
```

(first quote)

Also give `!` in the `<!doctype html>`

Answer (score 1):

By the way, i had trouble making this work in Firefox.
One thing to mention, is the path to the document needs to be absolute and not relative.

```
    var hownowPlugin = document.getElementById("winFirefoxPlugin");
    var version = hownowPlugin.GetOfficeVersion();
    hownowPlugin.EditDocument("http://example.com/word.doc", version);
```